# most searched terms block in drupal

Tags: drupal

I want to implement a block that displays the most searched items on my drupal site. Is there any module out there that does something similar?

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/top_searches looks like a good bet. Also check out the links in a Drupal forum post on the subject: http://drupal.org/node/789596